# Vite React doesn't properly build .jsx to .js

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm new to the dev world, specially to frontend tools like Vite and React.

I developed a tiny app with both of them, and everything went just fine. It is being used currently with no problems; but now I need to modify an array of values (that are being used in a dropdown), so basically just need to change some texts.

I went ahead, changed it and tried with both npm run build and vite build, but no changes were made to the final project (I'm at localhost atm, with vite serve).

It seems that in my project structure I have an 'assets' directory where vite is compiling my 'src' files (.jsx). Then, they are being compiled again into the dist one.

So when I change the string in the .jsx files, they do not translate into the 'assets' directory, so obviously not translating into the dist one either.

Here is my project structure:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrKTI.png)

My vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');
  return {
    define: {
      'process.env': env
    },
    plugins: [react()]
  }
})
```

Sorry if I'm not explaining myself really well, and thank you for any responses

Tried:

- Cleaning cache with npm cache clean --force
- Cleaning chrome cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it seemed that my yarn build was building some other files that were in the project.

I fixed it by correctly linking the files I wanted to build in the HTML script tags.